date and time display
Some time ago I changed the display of the date and time in the top bar, using Gnome tweaks.  Now, after upgrading to 24.4.1 LTS it has stopped working and shows "Tuesday 3 September Y | k:45;25" (with the correct minutes and seconds).
I would be happy to return to the normal form (though getting the year and month would be nice), but how can I do even that?

There's a new extension called Date Menu Formatter by Marcin Jakubowski.  It works.  Well done, Marcin!

Please click the gray check beside your answer to mark it as accepted. Clicking the check makes it change color from gray to green.
